# How to setup a pipeline to pull data from Redshift (SSH Tunnel) to Azure Data warehouse using ADF V1?

Tags: azure, amazon-redshift, azure-data-factory

How Can I pull data from Redshift where SSH Tunneling is used and put that data to Azure Data warehouse using the ADF V1?

Comment: What have you tried so far? how did it fail? please expand your question. what data are you pulling? how much data? one off or regular?

Comment: I cant tell you more about it unless the above is fixed using the ADF V1. Currently I want 100GB of data from redshift to Azure SQL Database, and my only option is ADF V1, because there are somE existing pipelines which are being used there, so I can use ADF V2. Can you tell me how can I use ADF V1 Redshift option by using SSL Tunneling?

Comment: Have you tried binding a integration runtime to your redshift linked service? You might not be able to do this with copy data tool of v1, but you should be able to do it with “author and deploy”

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-amazon-redshift-connector Try to follow this doc or use ODBC connector. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-odbc-connector

Comment: @FangLiu Can you elaborate on this more? Not sure I fully understand this.

Comment: @FangLiu I tried author and deploy but I am not sure which connector to use here can you hElp mE in doing this?

Comment: Hi Anmol001. Confirmed with the PROD team. SSH Tunnel is not supported currently, but it is in the back log.